# Implement Auto Tagging for EC2 and its associated resources in boto3

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, tags, boto3

A newbie to boto3, we have a requirement to implement specific tags to all resources in AWS, I would like to start with EC2.  My requirement is to apply specific tags to EC2 and its resources (ENI, volume, EIP..) when we create a Name tag with specific Value to an EC2 instance.  I did create a Lambda function and configured a trigger "CreateTags."  I am sort of able to come to a stage where I could filer the instance which I am trying to create a Name tag, but lost on how to query Name and tag with a specific Value and assign specific tags to it and its resources, need help.

```
import json

import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print('Event: ' + str(event))
    print(json.dumps(event))

    # Contain all the identifiers of EC2 resources founds in a given event.
    # IDs could be EC2 instances, EBS Volumes, EBS snapshots, ENIs, or AMIs.
    ids =[]

    try:
        region = event['region']
        detail = event['detail']
        eventname = detail['eventName']

        print('region: ' + region)
        print('eventName: ' + eventname)
        print('detail: ' + str(detail))

        if not detail['responseElements']:
            print('No responseElements found')
            if detail['errorCode']:
                print('errorCode: ' + detail['errorCode'])
            if detail['errorMessage']:
                print('errorMessage: ' + detail['errorMessage'])
            return False

        if eventname == 'CreateTags':
            items = detail['responseElements']['instancesSet']['items']
            for item in items:
                ids.append(item['instanceId'])
            print(ids)
            print('number of instances: ' + str(len(ids)))

            base = ec2.instances.filter(InstanceIds=ids)

            #loop through the instances
            for instance in base:
                for vol in instance.volumes.all():
                    ids.append(vol.id)
                for eni in instance.network_interfaces:
                    ids.append(eni.id)
        else:
            print('Not supported action')

        if 'Tags' in ids:
            for tags in ids['Tags']:
                if tags["Key"] == 'Name':
                    tag_value = tag["prod-app*"]
                    print('Tagging resource' + resourceid)
                    ec2.create_tags(Resources=ids, Tags=[
                        {'Key': 'Product', 'Value': 'trial1'},
                        {'Key': 'Compliance', 'Value': 'trial2'}])

        print('Done tagging.')

        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print('Something Went wrong: ' + str(e))
        return False
```

Comment: Let's start at the beginning... I see that you wish to use an AWS Lambda function. What events would you like to 'trigger' the Lambda function? Is it only when an Amazon EC2 instance is launched, or do you want tags to also change when things are attached/detached? Or are you trying to trigger on tags being _added_ to an instance, and then copy down the tags? Another approach would be to regularly scan resources and update missing tags, but that wouldn't necessarily catch resources that are 'detached', which presumably should _lose_ the associated tags?

Comment: Hello John, that's really a nice idea to regularly scan resources and update missing tags, but the only condition is to add missing tags based on the Value of a Name tag.  That means if Name tag has Value "ABC", add these tags to EC2 and its resoursces.